# Xamarin Forms Right center checkbox

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, checkbox

Im making an Android application and Im trying to center right checkbox on all rows in the listview, but I cant do it. 
I want do something like this. Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bjhD.jpg

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <RelativeLayout>

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Funcionarios}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  Margin="20"
                  ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <image:CircleImage Source="{Binding Imagem}" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="60" 
                                                   HeightRequest="60" BorderColor="Black" BorderThickness="2">

                                </image:CircleImage>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" FontSize="Large"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Zona}"/>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<ViewCell>
       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <image:CircleImage Source="{Binding Imagem}" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" BorderColor="Black" BorderThickness="2"> </image:CircleImage>                               
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                 <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" FontSize="Large"/>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Zona}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="End">
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="False" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```